# How to create array of static const arrays

Tags: c, arrays

In my .c file I had `jpg[4]` to check for jpg signature (using `memcmp()`) in certain file:

```
static const unsigned __int8 jpg[4] = { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xDB };
```

Comparison works great and now  I would like to add some more format signatures, for example:

```
static const unsigned __int8 png[8] = { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A };
```

I dont want to copy paste code with different signature variable. How do I create an array of such **not changing values** and iterate through each signature using `for(;;)`. I don't want to declare them inside methods.

I know it's some basic stuff, but I'm pretty new to C, so it's not so obvious to me.

In pseudo code:

```
bool isImg(bool * value)
{
for(int index = 0; index < signatures count; i+++) <-- for should iterate through signatures
    {
        // use signature[index] which is array of bytes { 0xFF, Ox... }
        // check signature
    }
}
```

Comment: Identifiers starting with `__` are reserved by the standard. Do not use!

Comment: Are you asking how to declare a 2 dimensional array? And C does not support _methods_, only _functions_

Comment: Yes. I do know how to do it inside function or constructor, but I have no idea how to declare it outside.

Comment: Please give more information, it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Do not use homebrew types if there are standard ones. For fixed bit-width use `int8_t` & friends from `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
static const unsigned __int8 jpg[4] = { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xDB };
static const unsigned __int8 png[8] = { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A };

static const unsigned __int8 *signatures[] = { jpg, png };
```

Now you can iterate through the `sigantures` array. But then you don't know the length of each signature in the `signatures` array.

You could get around this by encoding the length in the first element of each signature:

```
static const unsigned __int8 jpg[] = { 4, 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xDB };
static const unsigned __int8 png[] = { 8, 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A };

static const unsigned __int8 *signatures[] = { jpg, png };

bool isImg(bool * value)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof (signatures)) / (sizeof (__int8*)); i++)
  {
    const unsigned __int8 *signature = signatures[i];
    int signaturesize = signature[0]; // here: 4 for i==0, 8 for i==1

        // use signature[i] which is array of bytes { 0xFF, Ox... }
        // check signature
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I get size of array like this (for jpg): (integer type) sizeof(jpg)/sizeof(jpg[0]) ? Nevermind, you just edited with same suggestion as I though doing to get size. I'll test it now.

Comment: You sure signaturesize doesn't display 255 in the first case instead of 4?

Comment: @Dancia yes, provided the first element of `jpg` is `4` as in my example.

Comment: Is there a way to get size using only something like `int size = (int) sizeof(jpg)/sizeof(jpg[0])` without having 4 inside jpg? Because if not, it makes more sense to make something like `static const int signatureSize[2] = { 4, 8 };` and delete counting from actual signature

Comment: `int size = (int) sizeof(jpg)/sizeof(jpg[0])` works because the compiler know what `jpg` is, but if you do `sizeof(signature)/sizeof(signature[0])` you won't get the number of elements, because at that point `signature` has decayed into a pointer to `__int8` and the length of the array `signature` points to cannot be deduced. Having `int signatureSize[2] = { 4, 8 };` would work, but this is somewhat dangerous, because the order of the signatures in the `signatures` array must match the order of sizes in the `signatureSize` array and if it doesn't you will get unexpected behaviour.